# Confusion over critical point of a two variable function

Tags: analysis

Consider the function f(x,y) = cbrt(xy). Using the limit definitions of partial derivatives, it can be shown that both f_x and f_y exist at (0,0) and are equal to 0. By definition, shouldn’t this imply that (0,0) is a critical point? Wolfram says the function has no critical points. Does it have something to do with the partial derivatives not being continuous at that point? Or the fact that no other directional derivatives exist at that point?

Comment: what do you mean by cbrt?

Answer (score 2):

The partial derivatives of $f(x, y) = \sqrt[3]{xy}$ are

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{3} x^{-\frac{2}{3}} y^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{3} x^{\frac{1}{3}} y^{-\frac{2}{3}} $$

Both of these functions do *not* have a limit as $(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)$, as for example looking at the limit of $f_x$ along $y = x$ gives a result of $\infty$ coming from positive values of $x$ and $-\infty$ coming from negative values.

Answer (score 1):

A point of clarification:  by 'cbrt(xy)' I assume you mean the real-valued cube root; i.e., $$f(x,y) = \sqrt[3]{xy} = (xy)^{1/3}. \tag{1}$$

While the partial derivatives do exist and are equal to $0$, this does not imply that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.  In fact, we can see that along the line $x = y$, we have $f(x,x) = x^{2/3}$ and the derivative is not well-defined, since $$\frac{f(h,h) - f(0,0)}{h} = \frac{1}{h^{1/3}},$$ which is positive if $h > 0$ and negative if $h < 0$; so as $h \to 0^+$ from the right, this tends to $+\infty$, but as $h \to 0^-$ from the left, this tends to $-\infty$.  And a plot shows that $x^{2/3}$ has a cusp at $x = 0$.  This means $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Some sources include nondifferentiable points as [critical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)), which is a matter of definition.  If this is allowed, then $(0,0)$ is a critical point.